# Start of expression in haskell PCRE

Tags: regex, haskell, pcre

I am trying to look for a dollar sign at the start of an expression.
I would expect this to be `"^\\$"`, in that I have to escape the dollar sign to avoid it being seen as the end of line.  However, I'm seeing the following results:

```
import Text.Regex.PCRE

let x = "$100.00" :: Text

let m = show x =~ "$" :: Bool
print m

let m = show x =~ "^$" :: Bool
print m

let m = show x =~ "^\\$" :: Bool
print m
```

Yielding:

```
True
False
False
```

What am I missing?

### Update 1

If I try escaping to fewer or more "\" characters:

```
let m = show x =~ "^\$" :: Bool
print m

let m = show x =~ "^\\\$" :: Bool
print m
```

Both produce

```
Parse error (line 13, column 30): lexical error in string/character literal at character '$'
```

### Update 2

```
let y = "1$00.00" :: Text
let m = show y =~ "$" :: Bool
print m
True
```

Which is why I want `^\\$` rather than just `$`

### Update 3

When I don't use `show`

```
let m = x =~ "^\\$" :: Bool
print m
```

Produces

```
<interactive>:1:9: error:
    • No instance for (RegexLike Regex Text) arising from a use of ‘=~’
    • In the expression: x =~ "^\\$" :: Bool
      In an equation for ‘m’: m = x =~ "^\\$" :: Bool
```

Comment: Why are you calling `show` on Strings?

Comment: How about: `"^\$"`?

Comment: You don't really need a regular expression for this. `"$100.00" !! 0 == '$'` will suffice, as long as you know you don't have an empty string.

Comment: @Toto, "^\$" produces ``Parse error (line 9, column 30): lexical error in string/character literal at character '$'``

Comment: @chepner, I'm using this in a block with other more complicated expressions that do require regex, so I'm trying to keep my expression matching consistently regex.  Aside from that, I'm generally confused about this error, and would like to know the answer.  "^" should mean start and "\\$" should mean dollar sign literal.

Comment: @Carl, in my context, it's actually a Text not a string, so I'm using `show` to convert it.  I'll update my question.

Comment: @Mittenchops Try calling `length (show ("$100.00" :: Text))`. Does it produce the result you expected?

Comment: @amalloy, no length produces an error: ``Ambiguous occurrence ‘length’``

Comment: @amalloy, I think you are implying I should not use show, but as you can see in update 3, that throws an error.

Comment: Hint: My question contains the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Data.Text.unpack` is the function that works.

```
import Data.Text as T

let x = "$100.00" :: Text
print $ (T.unpack x)
print $ IHaskellPrelude.length (T.unpack x)
let m = ((T.unpack x) =~ "^\\$" :: Bool)
print m
```

Produces

```
"$100.00"
7
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `unpack` to convert `Text` to `String`, not `show`. `show x` adds quotes, which prevent your regex from matching.